# Opening a project directory in PhpStorm from the Terminal

Tags: bash, ide, phpstorm, intellij-13

I want to open a project directory in PhpStorm using `pstorm .`

I am aware that there are many threads that have discussed this issue, but I have not been able to completely solve my problem with the solutions from those threads.

Using the IntelliJ Toolbox, I click the gear icon (top right) and I enable the *Generate Shell Scripts* option. I set the *Shell script location* to `/usr/local/bin` (which is in my PATH). The *Shell Script Name* is specified as pstorm.

The first issue is that the script isn't generated in `/usr/local/bin`. Presumably since the Toolbox doesn't have write privileges at that location. I then set it somewhere where it has write privileges - something like `/home/username/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/bin`. The script is successfully generated there under pstorm:

```
# Generated by JetBrains Toolbox 1.20.7940 at 2021-03-24T16:55:42.325644

"/home/username/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PhpStorm/ch-0/203.7148.74/bin/phpstorm.sh" "$@"
```

I then copy that file to /usr/local/bin: `sudo cp pstorm /usr/local/bin`

I then open a terminal and navigate to my desired directory, opening said directory in PhpStorm with `pstorm .`

PhpStorm then opens the directory. However, PhpStorm is then 'locked' as a child to the (parent) terminal instance and closing the terminal also closes PhpStorm. A more complete explanation relating to this behaviour is given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032067/why-does-phpstorm-close-when-i-close-the-terminal)

I would really prefer that PhpStorm not be dependend on a terminal instance, much like when I run `code .` for VSCode.

Any ideas why it is doing this and how to 'solve' this behaviour?

Comment: [How to send jobs to background without stopping them?](https://serverfault.com/questions/41959/how-to-send-jobs-to-background-without-stopping-them)

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-193204 -- seems relevant

Comment: This helped me, https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/enable-shell-scripts-for-the-jetbrains-toolbox-app